# Set a preferences file from root for all users

Tags: macos, deployment, terminal

I am using Deploy Studio to image Mac computers and post imaging the computer. After imaging the computer I am running a script file to change some settings and add a user based on what we input. What I am having trouble doing is setting the screensaver preferences for the new user so that the computer will ask for a password after 15min of inactivity. The commands which modify the preferences file for the screensaver work themselves I just don't have a way to set them from the script that runs as root.

Here's the commands as they need to be, but I won't know the user until it's being run:

```
#Set Delay for 15 minutes
sudo  write /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay 500

#Enable AskForPassword
sudo write /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver askForPassword 1
```

**How can I get all users at runtime and run the command on each of their respective directories?**

Comment: Is there and error, or what seems to be the exact problem?

Comment: The script needs to have a username for the command to work, but I won't know the user until it's being run.

Comment: No, the script is being run at boot.Not sure eactly the term for that? Root?

Comment: Using `~/Library/Preferences` specifies the username preferences directory for any user.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command like this:

```
#Set Delay for 15 minutes
sudo write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay 500

#Enable AskForPassword
sudo write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver askForPassword 1
```

This will limit the change to the current host it's being set on:

```
#Set Delay for 15 minutes
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay 500

#Enable AskForPassword
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -int 1
```

Also, if the script is running as root then there's no probably no need to use `sudo`

Comment: I tried using both commands and neither worked. I think I need to specify the exact user directory. Is there a way to use the users found with "ls -al /Users/"?